# Retrieve numeric value from List<String> in java

Tags: java

Hi i have  List which is having both String and numeric value i need to  retrieve only numeric value from it.How do i retrieve the numeric value

```
public void printNumericValue(){
    ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("java");
        arrayList.add("1");
        arrayList.add("vava");
        arrayList.add("2");
       arrayList.add("javadd");
        arrayList.add("122");
        arrayList.add("vavaja");
        arrayList.add("20784");


}
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(arrayList.get(index))` with in try .. catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Integer.parseInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) but remember that this method can throw an exception for Strings that are not valid numbers, keeping this in mind you can create a method like this

```
static List<Integer> extractInteger(List<String> input) {
        List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String candidate : input) {
            try {
                output.add(Integer.parseInt(candidate));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```

Or in java8 you can do

```
List<Integer> output = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.stream().forEach(new Consumer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(String candidate) {
                try {
                    output.add(Integer.parseInt(candidate));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to parse the values. E.g.:

```
List<String> arrayList = // ArrayList from the OP
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

for (String s : arrayList) {
    try {
        result.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // A string which doesn't represent a number
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without using try catch

```
for (String string : arrayList) {
        char[] cs = string.toCharArray();
        boolean isnumeric = false;
        for (char c : cs) {
            if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
                isnumeric = false;
                break;
            } else {
                isnumeric = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isnumeric) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

    }
```